# How to implement cards expanding to modal in react native?

Tags: user-interface, mobile, react-native

I would like to implement cards, similar to what apple do in its redesigned AppStore(there is cards that expands into page, yet header and background image is animated into same parts of modal windows and same behavior happens when modal is being closed) . As example of what I mean: https://youtu.be/9myB9w1qRdM

What is right approach to do that?

Comment: I think what you need is like this one: https://github.com/ggomaeng/react-native-card-modal and it can be done with transformations and animations.

Comment: thats very near to what I want. Can you submit it like an answer so I bounty can go to you?

Comment: Sure im adding one now

Answer (score 2):

I think this is quite similar to what you are looking for: https://github.com/ggomaeng/react-native-card-modal

It uses Animation API and transformations.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-card-animated-modal

It uses Animation API too and you can customize the content of each cards and how it looks.

Example code from the repo:

```
import CardList from "react-native-card-animated-modal";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const now = new Date();
const CARDS = [
  {
    image: {
      uri:
        "http://www.gamespersecond.com/media/2011/07/battlefield-3-poster.jpg"
    },
    height: 300,
    renderItem: ({ item, index }) => (
      <View>
        <Text>Customizable Content</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
];

const App = () => (
  <CardList
    listProps={{
      ListHeaderComponent: () => (
        <View style={{ padding: 16, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 13,
              color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
            }}
          >
            {now.toDateString()}
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 32, fontWeight: "bold" }}>Featured</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }}
    data={CARDS}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
      /* Render card per item */
      if (item.renderItem) return item.renderItem({ item, index });

      /* Default card when not specified */
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Default Content</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }}
    renderDetails={({ item, index }) => (
      /* You can also provide custom content per item */
      <View style={{ paddingVertical: 30, paddingHorizontal: 16 }}>
        <Text style={{ color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)", fontSize: 18 }}>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </Text>
      </View>
    )}
  />
);
```

Comment: @ShashinBhayani Added code, and it's basically the code from the repo.